MS Word 365 - Unable to do anything but cancel after mail merge
I have one user with MS Office 365 that is unable to mail merge from our MS Access application.  The main merge is handled in VBA from MS Access here:
   'Set the merge data source to the text file just created,
   'and do the merge
   With appWord
      .ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
         Name:=strTextFile, _
         Format:=4
      .ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination = 0
      .ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Execute
      'Save newly created merge document
      .ActiveDocument.SaveAs strSaveNamePath
      'Close master merge document,
      .Documents(strDocName).Close _
         SaveChanges:=0
   End With

It creates the merged file and leaves the newly create file open.  But, the only option on the ribbon I can use is Cancel and if I try to open the saved merge result file, it says it is corrupted.
I've tried changing the Save Options to:

Unchecked AutoSave
Unchecked Save AutoRecover information
Unchecked Show additional places for saving, even if sign-in may be required
Checked Save to Computer by default
Set the default local file location to not be the OneDrive folder
Set the templates folder to be where the template is located.

I've tried creating a brand new template on the user's computer with one merge field to see if there was something wrong with the original template but that had the same issue.
I've verified the template and path are correct.

Turns out the user changed the default file type to .dotx instead of the normal .docx.  Office's attempts to help users with templates was conflicting with the save location (not the templates folder).  Once I changed the default file type back to .docx it works fine.
